# Using decorators on getters

Tags: javascript, typescript, decorator, babeljs, mobx

I'm trying to convert the following code:

```
class Bar {
  constructor() {
    extendRxObservable(this, {
      items$: myObservable()
    })
  }
}
```

Into this:

```
class Bar {
  @computedRx get items() {
    return myObservable()
  }
}
```

I've been trying to [read up on decorators](https://medium.com/google-developers/exploring-es7-decorators-76ecb65fb841#.icwxdfdpr) but I am totally confused as to how I can achieve this.

I'm using this together with mobX which has the [`@computed`](https://mobxjs.github.io/mobx/refguide/computed-decorator.html) decorator which uses [`extendObservable`](https://mobxjs.github.io/mobx/refguide/computed-decorator.html). However, it's written in TypeScript which doesn't quite match how things work in ecmascript. [`extendRxObservable`](https://gist.github.com/ronag/16f840fe783c4de30ea7f9c645ce324f) is implemented on top of [`extendObservable`](https://mobxjs.github.io/mobx/refguide/computed-decorator.html).

Comment: Decorators are ES8 at best, not ES6.

Comment: @Bergi: Yes? Still possible to use through https://github.com/loganfsmyth/babel-plugin-transform-decorators-legacy

Comment: @ronag He mentioned it because you had the question tagged as ES6.

Comment: @loganfsmyth: I see.

Comment: @ronag have you implemented `computedRx` decorator yourself?

Comment: I think the ES6 tag was ok because the author told it is TypeScript which compiles decorators down to ES5 with `experimentalDecorators` (or ES6)